# Loading file, checking for duplicates, skipping duplicates and printing them out at the end in java

Tags: java, file, input, duplicates

I am new to Java and i need to find a way to check if an incoming file has duplicate lines, skip those lines and not load them, and then at the end print out a message saying what the duplicates were.

Please help.

Comment: I have tried using .equals to try and compare one line with another but it does not seem to work, not sure if i need to use Scanner or not.

Also i cannot seem to get the syntax right anyway.

I need something like.

If a barcode is contained more then once in a file, to skip trying to load that line and move to the next.

Comment: That's a good start. This information should help others answer your question more easily/quickly, so I'd recommend editing your post to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you might need to read one line and compare with another file to line by line. Normally, you can use .equal, but you need to make sure you are reading one lie and it has been excluded change line code such as ¥n or ¥r. You had better to check the value using debugger. Better to share your code if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I quickly whipped up which might help you out:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class DuplicateChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testfile"));
            String line_read = "";
            line_read = in.readLine();
            while(line_read != null) {
                if ( lines.contains(line_read) ) {
                    System.out.println("Duplicate found: " + line_read);
                }
                lines.add(line_read);
                line_read = in.readLine();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf_ex) {

        } catch (IOException io_ex) {

        }
    }
}
```